# Java Accessing outer class variables from an inner class singleton

Tags: java, singleton, nested

I have an interface (`Node`) that is implemented by two classes: `White`, which I want to be a singleton, and `Black`, not a singleton. The problem is I want these classes to be enclosed by an outer class (`Outer`), which has a field of its own (`outerObject`). `White` should be a singleton, which means it should be static. But `Black` needs to be able to access the outer class fields, which means it cannot be static.

Here, if `White` is not static, then it's not really a singleton:

```
class Outer {
    interface Node {
        Node foo();
    }

    // I would like the White class to be a singleton class
    class White implements Node {
        Node foo() {
            return new Black();
        }
    }

    class Black implements Node {
        Node foo() {
            outerObject.doSomething();
            return this;
        }
    }

    Object outerObject;
}
```

But if I make `White` a static singleton, then it cannot instantiate a new `Black` without an enclosing `Outer`:

```
    enum White implements Node {
        INSTANCE;

        Node foo() {
            return new Black(); // This doesn't work because Black
                                // needs an enclosing outer class.
        }
    }
```

And if I were to make `Black` a static class, then it cannot access the field (`outerObject`) in the outer class:

```
    static class Black implements Node {
        Node foo() {
            outerObject.doSomething(); // can't access non-static field
            return this;
        }
    }
```

A simpler representation which captures the same problem is simply trying to access `outerObject` from a singleton `White`:

```
class Outer {
    enum White {
        INSTANCE;

        Node foo() {
            outerObject.doSomething();
            return this;
        }
    }

    Object outerObject;
}
```

I'd have to make `White` non-static to be able to access `outerObject`, but it should be static in order to be singleton.

Does anyone know if there is a solution to this? If it comes down to it, I could try to make a pseudo-singleton inner class (in the sense that each instance of the outer class can only have one instance of that inner class). Or just ditch the singleton pattern and manually declare only one `White`.

Comment: I think you may be overcomplicating things.  Why do you even need such a structure?

Comment: defenceThere's no way round this other than changing your design. A static inner class isn't tied to a specific instance of the outer class, so it can't create an instance of a non-static inner class, because that **is** tied to a specific outer instance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I am trying to implement a quad tree.

EDIT: The quad tree stores points and lines as contents. `White` nodes mean there is nothing in it. `Black` nodes mean there is one point in it. There are also `Grey` nodes, but I left them out of the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify on what instanse of Outer you want to create new Black. But probably it is not what you want.

```
    enum White implements Node {
        INSTANCE;

        public Node foo() {
            return new Outer().new Black(); // This will work
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've seen this before, but I need the new `Black` to be enclosed by the same `Outer` as the `White`. I know this is impossible if `White` is static. Maybe there is another non-static implementation of the singleton pattern.